# Android HttpURLConnect input stream and file writing

Tags: android, glassfish

I am working on an Android 1.6 application that isn't working and I am contacting a RESTful server to download a JSON object to import data to the application.
The manifest file has *usesPermissions* for **Internet** and **Write External Storage**.
Though I am not sure that my permissions are working.
What needs to happen is a PUT request needs to go to the server with a JSON string of the object control. The server updates the control object and passes it back.
I need to take a field out of the control object and save that to a file on the sdcard.  What have I done wrong or where can I find a better idea of what to do?
The network code is ported from a Java application where it works, I think it is dying at the line `InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();`.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    try{
        String uriAddress = "serveraddress";
        URI uri = new URI(uriAddress);
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        String putRequest = gson.toJson(control);
        objOut.writeObject(putRequest);
        out.flush();
        int x = conn.getResponseCode();
        out.close();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        String jsonString = (String) objIn.readObject();
        control = gson.fromJson(jsonString, WordToPictureMatchingDataTransferControl.class);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Net", e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("/sdcard/CAT/wtpm/wtpm.dat", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        //osw.write(gson.toJson(control.getWtpmdtArray()));
        osw.write("It Worked");
        osw.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("File", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here are the stack traces from the execution

```
03-16 23:01:15.105: ERROR/Net(23700): six8a.rdg.ac.uk/192.100.154.8:8080 - Connection refused
03-16 23:01:15.105: ERROR/Net(23700): six8a.rdg.ac.uk/192.100.154.8:8080 - Connection refused
03-16 23:01:15.105: WARN/System.err(23700): java.net.ConnectException: six8a.rdg.ac.uk/192.100.154.8:8080 - Connection refused
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
03-16 23:01:15.115: WARN/System.err(23700):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at uk.ac.reading.sse.mz014227.cat.CAT.updateExercises(CAT.java:123)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at uk.ac.reading.sse.mz014227.cat.CAT.onOptionsItemSelected(CAT.java:92)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2202)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:739)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:545)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
03-16 23:01:15.126: WARN/System.err(23700):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 23:01:15.135: ERROR/File(23700): File /sdcard/CAT/wtpm/wtpm.dat contains a path separator
03-16 23:01:15.135: ERROR/File(23700): File /sdcard/CAT/wtpm/wtpm.dat contains a path separator
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /sdcard/CAT/wtpm/wtpm.dat contains a path separator
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1641)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:415)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
03-16 23:01:15.135: WARN/System.err(23700):     at uk.ac.reading.sse.mz014227.cat.CAT.updateExercises(CAT.java:147)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at uk.ac.reading.sse.mz014227.cat.CAT.onOptionsItemSelected(CAT.java:92)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2202)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:739)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:545)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-16 23:01:15.146: WARN/System.err(23700):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The corrected code is

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    String jsonString = "";
    String encoding = "UTF-8";

    try{
        String uriAddress = "address";
        URI uri = new URI(uriAddress);
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        String putRequest = gson.toJson(control);
        Log.d("Gson", gson.toJson(control));
        out.write(putRequest);
        out.flush();
        int x = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Repsonse Code", "" + x);
        out.close();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(in, writer, encoding);
        jsonString = writer.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Net", e.getMessage());
        Log.e("Net", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Gson2", jsonString);
    control = gson.fromJson(jsonString, WordToPictureMatchingDataTransferControl.class);

    File file = new File("/sdcard/CAT/wtpm.dat");

    FileOutputStream binOutFile;
    ObjectOutputStream objOut;

    // initialise FileOutputStream
    try {
        binOutFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
        objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(binOutFile);
        objOut.writeObject(control.getWtpmdtArray());
        objOut.close();
        binOutFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if exception warn and return
        Log.e("File", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.e("File", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: when you say "I think it is dying at the line InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();" What do you mean? Is the app force closing? or just not behaving as expected? If it is force closing it will be easier for us to help if you post the output from you logcat.

Comment: logcat isn't posting anything.  I have had to line by line force a layout change to show how far it is getting. I can put a layout change before that line and it works if I put a layout change after that line then it doesn't change the layout.  So I think that it is getting to that line throwing an exception that isn't making it to logcat but I can't figure out why.

Comment: It seems the glassfish RESTful server is refusing the connection

Comment: I have advanced from a connection refused error to a java.io.FileNotFound error on the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson gson = new Gson();

```
String jsonString = "";
String encoding = "UTF-8";

try{
    String uriAddress = "address";
    URI uri = new URI(uriAddress);
    URL url = uri.toURL();
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    String putRequest = gson.toJson(control);
    Log.d("Gson", gson.toJson(control));
    out.write(putRequest);
    out.flush();
    int x = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d("Repsonse Code", "" + x);
    out.close();
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(in, writer, encoding);
    jsonString = writer.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("Net", e.getMessage());
    Log.e("Net", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.e("Gson2", jsonString);
control = gson.fromJson(jsonString, WordToPictureMatchingDataTransferControl.class);

File file = new File("/sdcard/CAT/wtpm.dat");

FileOutputStream binOutFile;
ObjectOutputStream objOut;

// initialise FileOutputStream
try {
    binOutFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
    objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(binOutFile);
    objOut.writeObject(control.getWtpmdtArray());
    objOut.close();
    binOutFile.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // if exception warn and return
    Log.e("File", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    Log.e("File", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}